# How to copy specific files from one folder to another from the command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a large folder of pictures (thousands), and I have a long list of files, by exact file name, that I need to copy to another folder using Windows commands, through `cmd` prompt only. I use Windows 7.

I want to know if there is a way I can select several specific files from this folder, by name, and copy them to another folder, using the terminal, without copying them individually?.

I know I can do it with `xcopy` but i want to copy specific types of files only say 'jpeg','bmp',etc.

Answer (score 7):

Try using

```
xcopy /d /y /s "\Your Image Folder\*.jpg" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Master Image Folder\"
```

Also you can simply use

```
copy *.<extension> <other folder>
```

**For example :**

```
copy C:\Users\desktop\*.jpg D:\backup
```

will copy all files with extension `.jpg` from path `C:\Users\desktop\` to `D:\backup\`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
xcopy /s "c:\source\*.jpeg" "c:\destination\"
```

should do the trick. Additionally, if you type `xcopy /?`, you should get the documentation. (you can replace `.jpeg` with whatever file extension you want.

The information on the page [Microsoft DOS xcopy command](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) provides considerably more information and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy c:\scr\*.jpg c:\dst
copy c:\src\*.bmp c:\dst
```